# How to exit from Lumia Flash screen (Flash and Gear icon)

Tags: 8.1

Suddenly my phone restarted and flash and gear icon appeared. Tried restarting with power button and volume down keys but phone restarts and shows same screen again.

[image]

Model: Lumia 720

My OS is Windows Phone 8.
Thank you

**Edit**
Letting the phone to completely drain the battery, charging it, turning it on and selecting the Reset your phone option solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

You will probably have to hard reset your phone using the [Windows Devices Recovery Tool](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/12379/windows-10-mobile-device-recovery-tool-faq).

Comment: This would not work, my phone would not show up when connected to PC.

Comment: Have you tried a soft-reset while the phone is connected to the PC and the WDRT is running?

Comment: No, I have did things mentioned in Edit which solved my problem. Thanks for a suggestion.

Comment: please add this as a separate answer and accept it